# Permanently added the ECDSA host key for IP address '140.82.113.4' to the list of known hosts in Cpanel

Tags: git, github, github-actions, cpanel, known-hosts

When trying to link a **Private repository** in my GitHub to my CPanel, after taking all the necessary steps, when I get to the part where I insert my SSH Link in CPanel, I get this error.

```
Error: (XID x7rhx7) “/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/bin/git” reported error code “128” when it ended: Warning: Permanently added the ECDSA host key for IP address '140.82.113.4' to the list of known hosts. Permission denied (publickey). fatal: Could not read from remote repository. Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to finally solve this by creating a "config" file inside the ".ssh" folder in my cpanel root folder. Then I added:

```
Host *
        IdentityFile=/home/sitename/.ssh/my_key
        UserKnownHostsFile ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

1. Replace "sitename" with the name in your cpanel's root folder.
2. Replace "my_key" with the name of the file that has your key.